# Replacement for jsdom in Node.js

Tags: node.js, jsdom

## Update

Node.js 4 is out now and it's fully supported by jsdom. The original question below is about Node.js 0.12.

If you keep getting weird messages like "jsdom 4.x onward only works on io.js, not Node.js", I recommend upgrading both Node.js and jsdom to the latest versions.

---

jsdom 4 has discontinued support for Node.js.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom):

> Note that as of our 4.0.0 release, jsdom no longer works with
>   Node.js™, and instead requires io.js. You are still welcome to install
>   a release in the 3.x series if you are stuck on legacy technology like
>   Node.js™.

(I've heard about the criticism around Joyent's management of Node.js, but the "legacy technology" here sounds a bit derogatory.)

While jsdom 3.1.2 still works fine, I would like to build new projects on a library that receives regular updates and supports Node.js. Is anybody aware of an alternative project that is still maintained by its authors?

Comment: There is one from Mozilla I believe... but I'm not able to find it right now.

Comment: It's ironic that you're interested in a new project that receives regular updates and is maintained by its authors, and yet you still use Node.js, which does not/is not.

Comment: @Domenic Thanks for your remark, but that's only half the truth ;-) The last Node.js update was released just [a few weeks ago](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joyent/node/master/ChangeLog). Note that this question was posted here before some of the most recent events, and indeed I'll have to update my post when the merge with io.js is finished.

Comment: I would call the contents of that changelog something very different than maintenance.

Comment: @Domenic I feel sorry for your dissatisfaction with "legacy technology like Node.js™".

Answer (score 3):

Might not be the end all solution but [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) does the trick on my end.  Be sure to read through their guide on where they fall short of jsdom